# Jquery: можно ли оптимизировать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть скрипт, проверяющий, верно ли введено слово в пропуск:

```js
var check = function(input, word) {
  input.keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == word) {
      $(this).css({'color':'green', 'border-bottom-color':'green'});
    }
    else {
      $(this).css({'color':'black', 'border-bottom-color':'gray'});
    }
  });
  input.blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == word) {
      $(this).css({'color':'green', 'border-bottom-color':'green'});
    }
    else {
      $(this).css({'color':'red', 'border-bottom-color':'red'});
    }
  });
}


check($('#am'), 'am');
check($('#has'), 'has');
check($('#will'), 'will');
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
I <input type="text" id="am" /> a student.<br />
She <input type="text" id="has" /> a dog.<br />
We <input type="text" id="will" /> come home tomorrow.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

По нему имеются два вопроса.

**ПЕРВЫЙ:** Можно ли как-то объединить keyup и blur? Понятно, что есть конструкция .on('keyup blur', function(){}), но в else там разные цвета.

**ВТОРОЙ:** На каждую проверку нужно вызывать функцию check со своими аргументами. Сейчас их 3, но будет и 33, и ещё больше. Есть ли какая-то возможность это оптимизировать?

Понятно, что можно создать два массива - с инпутами и со словами - и прогонять вызов функции в цикле, подставляя на каждой итерации соответствующие элементы массивов. Но мне не кажется, что это решение лучше имеющегося. Вдруг есть какой-то совершенно иной вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var check = function(input, word) {
  input.on('blur keyup', function() { // объединяем ивенты
    if ($(this).val() != word && event.type == 'blur') {
      $(this).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'border-bottom-color': 'red'
      });
    }else if($(this).val() != word && event.type == 'keyup') {
      $(this).css({
        'color': 'black',
        'border-bottom-color': 'black'
      });
    }else {
      $(this).css({
        'color': 'green',
        'border-bottom-color': 'green'
      });

    }
  })
};

$(".chekable").each(function() { // навешиваем функцию на все инпуты в наборе. 
  check($(this), $(this).data('answer'));
});
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

I <input type="text" id="am" class="chekable" data-answer="am" /> a student.<br /> She <input type="text" id="has" class="chekable" data-answer="has" /> a dog.<br /> We <input type="text" id="will" class="chekable" data-answer="will" /> come home tomorrow.
```

Comment: в keyup цвет должен стать черным. а не красным

Comment: @ Grundy обновил ответ

Comment: ну, по первому вопросу оптимизации не заметно, зато логика стала более громоздкой и запутанной :) так что в этой части я оставлю своё решение. а вот за .each спасибо! сам почему-то не додумал...

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function check(i) {
  //проверяем совпадает ли значение с его data-info атрибутом

  i.keyup(function(){
       $(this).css(($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-info")?{'color':'green', 'border-bottom-c olor':'green'}:{'color':'black', 'border-bottom-color':'gray'}));
  });
  i.blur(function(){
      $(this).css(($(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-info")?{'color':'green', 'border-bottom-
      color':'green'}:{'color':'black', 'border-bottom-color':'gray'}));
  });
}

$(".inp").each(function() { //задаем обработчик событий 
check($(this));
});
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
I <input type="text" class="inp" data-info="am"/> a student.<br />
She <input type="text" class="inp" data-info="has"/> a dog.<br />
We <input type="text" class="inp" data-info="will"/> come home tomorrow.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```